# BlenderKit Asset Bar turns black

Tags: add-on

The BlenderKit Asset Bar turns all black, how can I fix or debug the issue?

After enabling BlenderKit, I started searching. The Asset Bar showed up and actually displayed models. But when I then moved the mouse (into 3D viewport / towards the bar), it turns all black. The green bar at the bottom of models (assumingly a "downloaded" indicator) is visible and so is the pop-up with the models' details (except that the image in the pop-up is all black, too).

Blender: 2.90.1 (portable), Windows 10 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question after the issue went away without any intended action.

The bug tracking tool at https://developer.blender.org/ is a better source of information for such issues: a search for "blenderkit" reveals that other users had similar issues (not working, not displayed, even crashed), but many of these trouble tickets were then abandoned by the reporter.

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports and https://youtu.be/JTD0OJq_rF4 are great sources on what to consider while debugging/reporting.